# Extract basename from filename in array

Tags: php, arrays, extract, explode

i have array with following strings.
first im using explode "\n" and the output as below.

```
[1]=> string(121) "/Microsoft/Windows/Ravemp2300Handler/DeviceArrival/a.exe" 
[2]=> string(139) "/Microsoft/Windows/EventHandlers/Ravemp2300Arrival/b.exe" 
[3]=> string(89) "/Microsoft/Windows/DeviceHandlers/Rio600Handler/c.exe" 
[4]=> string(103) "/Microsoft/Windows/Rio600Handler/EventHandlers/d.exe"
```

the following array will be extracted a.exe, b.exe and so on as below.

```
[1]=> string(121) "a.exe" 
[2]=> string(139) "b.exe" 
[3]=> string(89) "c.exe" 
[4]=> string(103) "d.exe"
```

anyone have idea how to solve the problem? i really appreciate it. thank you in advance.

i got the solution, thanks to Leven and Emil Vikström for alternate solution.

```
$array2 = array_map('basename', $array1);
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear on what you are asking for here...

Comment: Just explode again on /.  What have you tried and what problems are you having?

Comment: i did, the strings in array will separated by space. im not sure how to strips the strings except the last word. sorry if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for basename():

```
$array2 = array_map('basename', $array1);
```

Comment: Yeah +1 for basename, this understands the concepts of file paths and filenames. Pseudo: for ($i=1;$i<length($array1);$i++) { $array2[$i] = basename($array1{$i]); }

Answer (score 1):

```
function lastPart($str) {
  return end(explode('/', $str));
}

$array2 = array_map('lastPart', $array1);
```

What this does is it applies the function `lastPart` to every element of the array. [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) is called a *[higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)* because it takes *another function* as it's argument, which is a very common idiom in what is called *functional programming*. PHP is not functional but I still like this type of solutions.

[array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) and [usort](http://php.net/usort) are two other higher-order functions well worth checking out.

For a more common *imperative* solution you may just run a [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) loop:

```
$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $value) {
  $array2[] = end(explode('/', $value));
}
```

Comment: This is what you're looking for @Stream

Comment: i'm not the one who asked the question.